# Collection for Nested List

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I am trying to use Java 8 features for my nested list.

I have a list of objects. The object has a list field. I need to get the values of that list and add it in another list.

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add("s1");
strings.add("s2");

List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
foos.add(new Foo(strings));
```

I've come out with this approach 
`foos.stream().map(Foo::getStrings).collect(Collectors.toList());`

This approach works if I set my new list like this:

```
List<List<String>> newList = foos.stream().map(Foo::getStrings).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I would like to have a `newList` like this:
`List<String> newList = ....;` so `s1`, `s2`, from `strings` list will be shown in `newList`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `flatMap`. Replace:

```
.map(Foo::getStrings)
```

with

```
.flatMap(f -> f.getStrings().stream())
```

or

```
.map(Foo::getStrings).flatMap(Collection::stream)
```

Comment: Both are showing `Incompatible types. Required List<String> but flatMap was inferred to Stream<R>: no instance(s) of type(s) R exist so that Stream<R> conforms to List<String>`. error.

Comment: @Eniss have you changed the type of `newList` from `List<List<String>>` to `List<String>`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried this approach and it works:               `userRoles.stream().map(RoleDTO::getPrivileges).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());`
But this part `.flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())` doesn't look so nice.

Comment: @Eniss that's just how the API is defined, you can't change that

Comment: @Lino so having 2 collection is okay? I thought it wan't right. Thanks

Comment: @Eniss what do you mean with 2 collections? the part `.flatMap(Collection::stream)` is equal to `.flatMap(c -> c.stream())`. It is not creating a new collection if you meant that